# extend tcl operator : is there a direct operator extension interface

Tags: tcl

If I want to introduce some new expression operator, e.g. "%%" to deal with some custom data structure, I will need to re-define "expr" command to recognize it. Is this right?

Basically TCL extension is at the command level, there is no interface to directly add new operator.

Could you confirm my understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators in Tcl are implemented directly in Tcl's bytecode engine; you can't extend them or modify their semantics. Not without editing the expression parser (written in C) or the bytecode engine itself (a compiler and an execution engine, both written in C). Extending this part of Tcl directly is rather difficult. (You're looking at `tclParseExpr.c`, `tclCompExpr.c` and `tclExecute.c` *at least* to make things work, and quite possibly the other `tclParse*` and `tclComp*` files too, as well as the assembler and maybe the disassembler. Not to be taken on lightly!)

### However…

You *can* write your own command that interprets a string as anything you want, including an expression involving whatever new operators you desire. This is what [VecTcl](http://auriocus.github.io/VecTcl/) does. Under the covers, it converts its expression language into calls to Tcl commands that implement the various operators (some of which are implemented in C, but as a normal extension package, so that's nothing unusual).

Effectively, it converts an invoke of one of its expressions:

```
vexpr {3*x}
```

into something a bit like this:

```
numarray::* 3 [set x]
```

which it then can execute using Tcl's bytecode engine (frankly, a trivial execution, but it makes more sense in more complex examples; see the [VecTcl tutorial](http://auriocus.github.io/VecTcl/tutorial.html), which is a bit too long to reproduce here).

Answer (score 2):

The [mathop](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm) manual page calls out explicitly that while you can access the expr operators using the `::tcl::mathop` namespace you cannot add new ones nor redefine the existing ones there. You can add you expr functions using the `tcl::mathfunc` namespace as documented in the [expr](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm) man page so if a function will do that is the simplest method to do what you want.

Otherwise you could intercept the expr command itself. If you rename the expr command and define your own replacement you can do some expression parsing and replace your custom operator with a function call or pass the expression on to the real implementation. Below is a trivial example.

```
rename expr _expr
proc expr {args} {puts "called expr $args"; _expr {*}$args}
```

In short, your understanding is correct. You cannot inject new operators into the `expr` expression parser.

Comment: The mathop commands are only special in that they generate efficient bytecode. Changing them doesn't affect the expression engine itself; the functionality confluence is deeper inside Tcl.